# How to trigger c# method from anchor tag in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, anchor

I have an anchor tag in .aspx page as below:

```
<a href="#divrecentQ" runat="server" id="linkdivrecentQ" onclick="alert()" onserverclick="divrecentQInit" aria-controls="divrecentQ" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Click</a>
```

I want to tigger c# method using this tag.

```
protected void divrecentQInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log.Debug("divrecentQInit is called");

}
```

Problem is: divrecentQInit method is not getting called.

Thanks for help.

Not: I do not want to use LinkButton of asp.net since it doesnt work very well with bootstrap.

Comment: Make a call via ajax

Comment: What do you mean linkbuttons don't work well with Bootstrap? I have used the 2 together successfully in most of my recent projects. You could use an anchor tag but you would most likely need to then use JQuery and AJAX to fire the serverside code. 

It may be easier to just sort out the bootstrap linkbutton issue you have

Comment: Have u used bootstrap tabs with linkButton?? I did try this, but then click didnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Method call event(`onServerClick`) is **case-sensitive**, Use

```
onServerClick="divrecentQInit"
```

instead of

```
onserverclick="divrecentQInit"
```

and additionally I would suggest using `<asp:LinkButton` to achieve the same(you would not need `onServerClick` in this case, `OnClick` instead )

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="divrecentQInit" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**asp:LinkButton**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" 
           Text="Click Me" 
           Font-Names="Verdana" 
           Font-Size="14pt" 
           OnClick="LinkButton_Click" 
           runat="server"/>
```

In your code behind:

```
  public void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
      //stuff.
  }
```

Comment: I don't want to use LinkButton since it doesnt work well with bootstrap. Can we do this with anchor tag?

Comment: @DKR Bootstrap works perfectly fine with `LinkButton`. You can use the `CssClass` property to provide the relevant bootstrap class name